# Regarding running an application in Tizen Web Simulator

Tags: simulator, tizen

I want to run a Smart TV application in Tizen Studio emulator. The application was not originally created using Tizen studio. The application is made using JavaScript library "TV Application Layer". 
The application can be cloned from https://github.com/bbc/talexample .

To run the application in web browser, do the following steps using cmd prompt or git bash:

1. git clone git@github.com:bbc/talexample.git
2. cd talexample
3. npm install
4. npm start
5. Navigate to http://localhost:1337/

I can run this app in web browser. I can also run any application in the Tizen emulator, which was originally created in Tizen Studio. But I don't know how to run the above mentioned Smart TV app in Tizen Studio Emulator/Simulator. When I try to run in the emulator, it gives the following error:

> "Launching New_Configuration" has encountered a problem. This is an
>   error in the configuration file.

Maybe, it needs some configuration in both the Tizen Studio emulator and the Smart TV application.
Please, tell me any solutions to run the app in Tizen Studio emulator.

Comment: May you post the Tizen config.xml project file? Maybe there are some typos or missing tags. On the other hand please note Tizen TV apps needs most its resources built in the app package (wgt)

Comment: Yes I know TAL does not include the config.xml file but it is mandatory for Tizen apps to include it. You can create a sample project (File > New > Tizen project > Sample tv-extension). Try yo use the sample project as base for your app, but again, you will need use a local web app built in the wgt package, because as far I remember TAL generates the app on the fly

Comment: The smart tv application which I have mentioned above to clone  from github, does not have config.xml file.
Maybe, I need to add some files, related to tizen, in the application's package, which can make that application run in the tizen simulator.